# How to get Nifi to dynamically create indices when using PutElasticSearchRecord Processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm currently using Apache Nifi to push data into Elasticsearch.  Data is sent a single index but am looking to route the data dynamically to different indices based on the contents of the `client_id` field.

I have a `QueryRecord` processor doing some filtering before either sending to Elasticsearch or discarding. The `QueryProcessor` is set with a `JsonTreeReader` and `JsonRecordWriter`

How would I go about setting the index setting in `PutElasticSearchRecord` to use the contents of field `client_id` as the index name?

Answer (score 1):

[PutElasticsearchRecord](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-elasticsearch-restapi-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.PutElasticsearchRecord/) has two options for determining the Index.

1. You can set the `Index` property, which can either be a static value or use Expression Language to retrieve the value from Attributes. You could use PartitionRecord to bucket Records into FlowFiles by the value of `client_id`.
2. You can set `Index Record Path` which will use a [RecordPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html) to retrieve the value from the content of the Record. A RecordPath of `/client_id` would be what you want in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I suppose I'm still slightly off on this.  If I leave the `index` field blank and set the `Index Record Path` to `/client_id` that would automatically create indices based on the value of `/client_id` ?  If I had two fields I decided to concatenate to create the index such as `/client_id` + /`admin_level` would I be able to still add that in the `Index Record Path` like `${/client_id}-${admin_level}` ?

Comment: Setting `Index Record Path` will populate the Index with whatever the value of `/client_id` is. Automatically creating indexes is handled by ES, so you'll need to make sure ES is configured to automatically create indexes. If you want to concat two fields, you'd still need to use RecordPaths, and use the `concat()` function - e.g. `concat(/client_id, '-', /admin_level)`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `Index Record Path` property and providing the record path of the index field.